# Hosting XP 32bit as an Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, windows-xp-sp3

We want to replicate a clients environment on Azure for test/debugging reasons. The only issue is it's a 32 bit XP.

Does anyone know if I can host this on Azure?

Ta

Ross

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Windows Server instances can be used in Azure (Technically they are a special Azure Guest OS, but really they're versions of Windows Server). If you need XP then I'd suggest using a local VM in something like VirtualBox or VMware Workstation

Comment: Do you have a link to something that states only server instances can be used? I know from a licensing POV thats probably the case, but this machine would not be available outside our VPN so I don't think that would be an issue.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windowsazure/ee924680.aspx - Basically you don't get a regular OS image on Azure, you get special instances that are Azure specific (which are actually just Windows Server under the hood) - They aren't in the general cloud VPS business so you don't get much choice in the way of OS.

Comment: hmm, thats rubbish. Guess I probably need to look for another supplier for this then. Ta

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need a "local VM" in order to run Windows XP on Azure? Why not pick any modern OS in Azure, then install Windows XP as a Hyper-V virtual machine on Azure. This way, users can connect to the Azure server and then launch the Windows XP VM...

See:
http://fabriccontroller.net/running-a-legacy-os-in-a-windows-azure-virtual-machine-windows-xp-windows-server-2003/

and

http://morgansimonsen.com/2014/03/05/will-it-run-how-to-run-your-favorite-legacy-os-in-a-windows-azure-vm/